# How do I update a React state from previously fetched data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, state

I new to React and JS and still learning, I'm trying to create a website to show data from the SWAPI API, specifically the People data. If I fetch the the first page of people, there is a field called 'next' which has the url to retrieve the next page, as so on. I want to be able to use this field in a loop to fetch all the pages of data. Here's a sample of the first page:

```
{
    "count": 82,
    "next": "http://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Luke Skywalker",
            "height": "172",
            "mass": "77",
            "hair_color": "blond",
            "skin_color": "fair",
            "eye_color": "blue", ...
```

So once I have fetched `/people/` then I would want to fetch `/people/?page=2`
Here's the relevant code I have so far...

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            people: [],
            url: '',
            searchfield: ''
        }
    }
    // Find first page of 'people' then loop through each page adding 'data.results' to 'people' state array
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ url: 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/' }, () => {
            console.log('initial url is', this.state.url)   
                for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                    console.log('next url is', this.state.url)
                    fetch(this.state.url)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => this.setState((prevstate) => {
                        return {people: prevstate.people.concat(data.results), url: data.next}
                        }))
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                    });
                }
            });
        }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState) {
        if(prevState.url !== this.state.url) {
            console.log('* new url is', this.state.url)
        }
    }
```

I have a fixed loop `i` just now until I can get it working correctly otherwise it would loop indefinitely. 
My problem is that when trying to update the url state with the address of the next page it doesn't happen until the loop has finished, here's the output from the logs above.

```
* new url is https://swapi.dev/api/people/
initial url is https://swapi.dev/api/people/
4 next url is https://swapi.dev/api/people/  < this happens 4 times
* new url is http://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2
```

I thought adding the state change in the return field would be enough but is wasn't so I tried adding the componentDidUpdate function to try and trigger the state change, but I don't think it helped. I'm also curious how the log from componentDidUpdate appears first when nothing has been updated yet?

At the moment all this does is concatenate the same 4 pages into the people array (and the console complains about it).

So my question is, how can I set the url state correctly using data from a previous fetch?

EDIT: Ok, one thing I forgot to add to my question is that I was planning on making this fetch generic so that it could accept any of the categories on SWAPI and use the 'next' field to determine when to stop fetching data. I did have a previous piece of code which was similar to Yousafs answer, I fetched the first page then used the count to loop through all the individual pages, but that meant 72 fetches! that's when looping through the pages seemed a better bet. I have a better idea how to do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to fetch data in a loop is all wrong. `fetch` function returns a promise and the actual request is made asynchronously. What you should do is save all the promises returned by `fetch` function in an array and then resolve all those promises using [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) function.

To fetch the data you want, follow these steps:

1. in `componentDidMount` function, create an array that will hold all the promises returned by `fetch` function. The create a loop and add all the promises returned by `fetch` function in the you created previously.
2. After that, call `Promise.all` function and pass the array that contains all the promises. `Promise.all` will return an array of [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) objects. Then you need to call [.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) function on all those `Response` objects to get the actual data returned by the API.

here's how your `componentDidMount` function should look like.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const requests = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      requests.push(fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=' + i));
    }

    Promise.all(requests)
      .then(res => Promise.all(res.map(r => r.json())))
      .then(data => {
        const people = [];

        data.forEach(d => people.push(...d.results));

        this.setState({ people });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
}
```

above written `componentDidMount` function can also be written using [async-await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) syntax.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const requests = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      requests.push(fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=' + i));
    }

    try {
      const responseArr = await Promise.all(requests);
      const data = await Promise.all(responseArr.map(r => r.json()));

      const people = [];
      data.forEach(d => people.push(...d.results));

      this.setState({ people });

    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

### Demo

Here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7ahcue?file=index.js) that fetches data of first 3 pages from the Swapi API and displays the names of all the people.

Comment: I've marked your reply as the answer as it helps me better understand async requests, but if you read my question edit I forgot to add what I was planning on doing. I have an idea now that I could use your approach but use the 'count' field to determine how many pages I need to bundle in to the array of promises (which I didn't know you could do!) before processing them, i.e. count/10 then if the remainder isn't zero add 1, otherwise use as is.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch()` is [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Concepts). When you call `fetch`, it immediately returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and schedules the actual fetch to be performed later. It doesn't actually do the work inline as you might be used to with other languages/frameworks.

So your `for` loop starts at 0, calls `fetch` which *schedules* a fetch (but does not actually perform a fetch) with the current URL, goes to 1, schedules a fetch with the same URL (remember, it hasn't changed since the previous fetch hasn't actually executed yet), etc.

Once your `for` loop and the callback function have exited, the `fetch`s execute. Now, in React, every time you update the state, the component re-renders. This is pretty expensive to compute so React tries to do it as little as possible. One of the optimizations that React makes is that it [makes state changes asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Concepts) so that a bunch of state changes in a row get aggregated into one big state change. You're only seeing one log from `componentDidUpdate` because it's only actually updating once.

There's a few ways you can go about solving this problem. My recommendation is to make use of JavaScript's [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) syntax. Put `async` before the arrow function in the original `setState` callback and put `await` before the `fetch`.