# Recursion : return vs boolean exit

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, fetch

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and I've been working with this api and I'm basically just testing how these recursive calls work: as you can see, I'm trying to stop the call once I hit data.id == 6.

What's the difference between using 'return' to get out of a recursive call versus using a boolean?
I would think they'd produce the same output; however, they don't. The boolean produces the expected results, while the 'return' produces an infinite loop. I thought the return would be the last call. Where is the hole in my thought process?

Also, side note, should you always use await when calling api calls? When I took await off, it produced an infinite loop, even with the boolean method. Why's that?

Thank you for your time.

```
    let bool = true;
    async function foo(index) {

        let var2 = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${index}`)
        .then(blob => blob.json())
        .then(data => {
            if(data.id == 6) {
                return;
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));


        foo(++index);
}
```

```
let bool = true;
async function foo(index) {

    let var2 = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${index}`)
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    .then(data => {
        if(data.id == 6) {
            bool = false;
        }
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

    if(bool) {
        foo(++index);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my experience, return is a more readable way to break out of the recursive and since you're using async await, it can be simplified and read like sync code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing `async`/`await` and `Promise`, but really these are two versions of the same thing.

Say you want something from a remote service, in this case your `fetch('https...` - you're really sending a request and then want to do something else when it's done. This used to be done with a *callback*:

```js
// pseudocode, not actual JS
oldFetch('https...', result => {
    // This code fires when the fetch finishes
    someOtherAsyncRequest(..., secondREesult => {
        // This fires when the second async action is done
    });
});

// Code here fires immediately, it doesn't wait for callbacks
```

You'd quickly get to a problem where callbacks were nested in callbacks and error tracking is a mess. The solution is `Promise` - instead of a callback function the `Promise` would have `then` called when it succeeded, or `catch` when it failed. This lets you *chain* these callback requests together whenever the next function also returns a `Promise`

```js
fetch(`https...`)                     // Returns a promise with the response
    .then(blob => blob.json())        // Returns a promise when the JSON is finished parsing
    .then(data => {                   // Doesn't return anything, so chain stops
        if(data.id == 6) {
            bool = false;
        }
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));  // Catch exceptions
```

Note that none of these `then`/`catch` statements stop the code executing, they really just wrap the callback in an object that lets you manage them better.

`async`/`await` is just syntax to make `Promise` easy to use, you still have `Promise` under the hood and can switch between them, but `async`/`await` is *much* easier to read.

`async` says *this function returns a `Promise`* (but it doesn't have to).

`await` says *put all the code after this in the `then(...`*.

Put them together and the code is much more readable:

```js
// Does exactly the same as the previous code example
try {
    const blob = await fetch(`https...`);
    const data = await blob.json();
    if(data.id == 6) {
        bool = false;
    }
    console.log(data);
}
catch(err) {  // Catch exceptions - if using await anything async can be in a regular try-catch
   console.log(err);
}
```

Let's apply this to your function. The reason it only works with `await` is that when that isn't there the whole function finishes before the `then` code is called, but with it the rest of the function is in another `then`.

You're mixing syntax so let's just use `async`/`await`:

```js
async function foo(index) { // async means this function can return a Promise
    try {
        const blob = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${index}`);
        const data = await blob.json();

        if(data.id == 6)
            return; // await means this will exit the parent function
       
        console.log(data);
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    await foo(++index);
}
```

> What's the difference between using 'return' to get out of a recursive call versus using a boolean?

You're only returning from the *callback*, you need to either handle that by resolving the `Promise` or just awaiting it.

> When I took await off, it produced an infinite loop, even with the boolean method. Why's that?

Your `let bool = true;` is global, and if you don't `await fetch(...` the next line executes immediately, calling `foo`. JS will complete the synchronous code before checking for the result of `fetch`, so you'll run out of recursion before any `fetch` results change the `bool = false`.

> should you always use await when calling api calls?

If the API is `async` or web based then yes. As a general rule once some code is `async` all of it must be - you can't (or shouldn't) call asynchronous methods with synchronous code. Best practice is to use `async`/`await` *everywhere* and design for it.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed response. This helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are returning inside a Promise. So the Promise will be returned, that means, in your case, var2 will be the value of return (which is undefined). However, you're calling foo again without any constraint, so it will be called always in the first case. In the second example you give, you added a constraint to the recursive call, so that's why it's not called anymore.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should understand couple of things about your code:

1. this is not a correct way to make multiple `async` requests.
2. You have mixed `async-await` syntax with `promise-chaining`.

In first code example, using a `return`, inside the `then` block, to stop recursion leads to infinite loop because `return` inside the `then` block only returns from the callback function passed to `then` function. It doesn't returns from the outer function.

In second code example, when the value of `bool` variable is set to false, function stops calling itself recursively.

To correctly make multiple requests, use `Promise.all()` function. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62393601/6094348) that shows how to make multiple requests using `Promise.all()` function.

> should you always use await when calling api calls?

Inside `async` functions, yes and you can't use `await` keyword outside an `async` function

> When I took await off, it produced an infinite loop, even with the
> boolean method. Why's that?

In this case, you are not awaiting the result of the request before calling the function again, this leads to infinite recursion.

You could change your code as shown below to get expected result

```
async function foo(index) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${index}`);
    const data = await response.json();

    if (data.id === 6) {
      return;
    }

    foo(++index);

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. I hadn't realized that I was only returning from the callback.  I appreciate the detailed response

Answer (score 1):

This bit in the middle of your function:

```
data => {
  if (data.id == 6) {
    return;
  }
}
```

Is a function. The return inside it returns *from this function only*. So if data.id is 6, return. And if not, we reach the end of this function -- also return. Therefore the return here *has no effect at all*.